# In a panel containing a lot of Web.UI.UserControls, how can I ensure a specific one is in the user's view upon Page_Load?

Tags: asp.net, scroll

On a given web page, in a asp:Panel, I've added a bunch of UserControl elements (to the .Controls list).  Upon Page_Load, the 1st (top) element is always visible (i.e. the vertical scroll position is at the Top).  Based upon an "id" value that was passed in via the browser (e.g. foo.com/pagename?id=44), I want to "go" to the 44th usercontrol upon completion of Page_Load.  I have tried setting the uc's Focus(), but that has no effect on its (positional) visibility.  This is a postback=false case (i.e. first time loading the page).  I don't know if I should look for a scrollbar-oriented solution, or ???